# Mail merge vba, header doesnt get the informations

Tags: vba, ms-word

Hello i have a code here. When I run it, I get all the documents saved individually as desired. The problem is

1. the saved documents are still linked to an excel list as a mail merge, thats the small problem. But if I delete the mail merge funkction in created document. The Header is again back to his ref. I mean there is <Sensore_name> for example instead of sensor xy

I am open for new codes and suggestions. I just want the code to store the mail merge document individually, in a desired folder and with a desired name

My code:

```
Sub SpeichernAlsDateien()
Dim i As Integer
Dim doc As Document
Dim Elemente As MailMergeDataFields
Dim Element As MailMergeDataField
Dim Speicherpfad As String
Dim AnzahlElemente As Integer
Dim ElementIndex As Integer

' Define the storage path
Speicherpfad = AbfrageFenster.PfadAutTextBox

' Query user input via the user interface
ShowUserForm

' actual Dokument
Set doc = ThisDocument

' Elements of the mail merge
Set Elemente = doc.MailMerge.DataSource.DataFields

' Limit the number of elements to the number entered or the number of data records, whichever is smaller

AnzahlElemente = IIf(doc.MailMerge.DataSource.RecordCount < AbfrageFenster.AnzahlTextBox, doc.MailMerge.DataSource.RecordCount, AbfrageFenster.AnzahlTextBox)

' loop elements
For i = 1 To AnzahlElemente
    ' Single element based on user input
    Set Element = Elemente.Item(AbfrageFenster.IndexTextBox)

    ' Save element in separate file
    doc.MailMerge.DataSource.FirstRecord = i
    doc.MailMerge.DataSource.LastRecord = i
    doc.MailMerge.DataSource.ActiveRecord = i

    ' konstant (wdFormatDocumentDefault)
    doc.SaveAs2 Speicherpfad & Element.Value & ".docx", 16 ' 16 entspricht wdFormatDocumentDefault
Next i

' msg box
MsgBox "--> Alle Dateien wurden abgelegt im Ordner: " & Speicherpfad & vbCrLf & "---------------", vbInformation
End Sub
```

Comment: Your code isn't executing the mailmerge. See *Send Mailmerge Output to Individual Files* in the **Mailmerge Tips and Tricks** page at: 
https://www.msofficeforums.com/mail-merge/21803-mailmerge-tips-tricks.html

Comment: @macropod I already see that post but couldnt find an answer :/

Comment: @CihanDincel have you change your code to define the destination _wdSendToNewDocument_, execute the Mailmerge (_.execute_) and then save the new generated file?

Comment: @CihanDincel If you didn't see the solution, that's because you didn't examine the code closely enough. Indeed, you could quite possibly get away the doing no more than copy/paste that code into your document and have it work for you.

Comment: @Shrotter how do I do that? :/ still couldnt finde a answer. Also tried the codes what macropod wrote...